# Picking Cards and Probabilities

Tags: probability

If you have a regular deck of 52 cards, with Jack, Queen, King, and Ace defined as *top cards,* what is the probability that you will pick:

1. Two top cards and four non-top cards?
2. Three top cards in the same suit and any three cards in another suit?
3. Three top cards not all in the same suit, and any three non-top cards?
4. Six non-top cards all in the same suit? (For example 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, all in spades)
5. Two different pairs of top cards (e.g. Q-Q, A-A) and any two cards each different
   from both pairs? (The last two cards may be a pair, and they may be top cards.)

---

These are the answers I have, but I'm not very confident in them:

2. $$P=\dfrac{\binom{36}3\binom{16}3\binom{9}3\binom{4}3}{\binom{52}6}$$
3. $$P=\dfrac{(\binom{16}3-\binom{4}3)\binom{36}3}{\binom{52}6}$$
4. $$P=\dfrac{\binom{36}6\binom{9}6}{\binom{52}6}$$
5. $$P=\dfrac{\binom{4}2\binom{4}2\binom{4}2\binom{44}2}{\binom{52}6}$$
   Any help you could give me at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quite a lot of questions. What work have you done on them ? Are you stuck on all of them ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know where to begin. Any help - even just with starting - would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the answers you posted for problems 2, 3, 4, and 5 rather than 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I thought I had fixed that before posting

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me do the first one, then you can try some more !

A deck will have $16$ top cards (choose $2$ from them), and $36$ others (choose $4$ from them)

Pr $= \dfrac{\binom{16}2\binom{36}4}{\binom{52}6}$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm just wondering if, for 3, you could help me specify that the top cards have to be in different suits?

Comment: @Doe Choose the three top cards, then subtract the number of selections in which they are all of the same suit.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks for the help. I think I have the rest but I'm not sure about the last one. Would it be (13 choose 2)(4 choose 2)(4 choose 2)(11 choose 1)(4 choose 1)(36 choose 2) on the numerator?

Comment: @Doe  That is incorrect.  I suggest that you edit your question to include your proposed solutions so that you get feedback on them.  For the last question, you must choose two of the four ranks (Jack, Queen, King, Ace) of top cards, select two of the four suits for each of the selected ranks, then select two of the $44$ cards in the deck that have ranks different from the two pairs that you selected.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks, I've given that a try, although I'm not sure if I've done it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the probability that you will pick two top cards and four non-top cards?

true blue anil has provided you with a correct answer to the first question.

> What is the probability that you will pick three top cards in the same suit and any three cards in another suit?

We must select one of the four suits from which to pick the top cards, select three of the four top cards in that suit, pick one of the three remaining suits, then select three of the thirteen cards in that suit.

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{13}{3}$$

from which you can calculate the probability.

> What is the probability that you will three top cards not all in the same suit and any three non-top cards?

We must select three of the sixteen top cards.  From these selections, we must exclude those selections in which we pick three top cards from the same suit.

Those selections in which three top cards are selected from the same suit require selecting one of the four suits and three of the four top cards in that suit. Hence, the number of ways of selecting three top cards from the same suit is

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{3}$$

Thus, the number of ways to select three top cards that are not all of the same suit is

> $$\binom{16}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{3}$$

We must also select three of the $36$ non-top cards.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting three top cards that are not all of the same suit and any three non-top cards is

> $$\left[\binom{16}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{3}\right]\binom{36}{3}$$

from which you can calculate the probability.

> What is the probability that you will pick six non-top cards all in the same suit?

To select six non-top cards all in the same suit, we must select one of the four suits and six of the nine non-top cards in that suit.

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{9}{6}$$

from which you can calculate the probability.

> What is the probability that you will pick two different pairs of top cards and any two cards different from both pairs?

You have answered this question correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, it really makes more sense now.